# R - Adjust size of all plots included in a grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to adjust the size of all plots (p1, p2, p3, and p4) which are inside a  `grid.arrange`. When I delete an element of the plot (such as the x title or the x-axis text) the plot is adjusted automatically, but I want the same square dimension for all plots.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using facets instead? Seems like the appropriate use case for facets.

Comment: I think using `facet_wrap` is the best option too, but the problem is that I have four individual plots made with different databases, and I don't know how to merge all plots using that function...

Comment: Right, that's fair (and probably a different question altogether). I find that [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) typically does a nice job at aligning the panels of sub-plots, so maybe that is worth trying out?

Comment: Thanks!! I used that package and the result is really fine!! If you want, write your comment as an answer and I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because patchwork aligns plots by the panels, the result is nice and stable when certain (axis) elements are missing. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#> Warning: package 'patchwork' was built under R version 4.0.3

plot <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()

p1 <- plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
p2 <- plot + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
p3 <- plot + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
p4 <- plot + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())

p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + plot_layout(2, 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>